# Как получить атрибут d для тега <path>?

Tags: html, svg

Нужно разместить иконку из сайта https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery в тег `<path>`, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кликните на иконку, вверху будет кнопка загрузки SVG:

[image: кнопка загрузки SVG иконки шрифта]

В этом SVG есть `path` с атрибутом `d`